# How to prepend content of a form on form submit using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit

I am trying to learn angularJS and have problem figuring out how to solve this issue. I am trying to prepend content of the form when user submit the form. This is my code but it's not working. Can anyone help me to figure out where the problem is? Thanks!

```js
angular.module("displayText", [])
  .controller("submitText", function($scope) {
    $scope.outputArr = [];
    $scope.print = function() {
        $scope.outputArr.push($scope.inputText);
        $scope.inputText = '';
      };
    };
  });
```

```html
<body ng-app="displayText">
  <div ng-controller="submitText">
    <form method="get" action="#">
      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="inputText" required/>
      <button ng-click="print(inputText)">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p ng-repeat="text in outputArr">{{text}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this piece of code inside the `submitText` controller div

```
<div>
    <p ng-repeat="text in outputArr">{{text}}</p>
</div>
```

then you whole code should be like

```
<div ng-controller="submitText">
   <form method="get" action="#">
      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="inputText" required/>
      <button ng-click="print(inputText)">Submit</button>
   </form>

  <div>
      <p ng-repeat="text in outputArr">{{text}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Nd0S92R3pyjLAT3SQiq?p=preview)

---

in your case the `ng-repeat="text in outputArr"` is out of the controller that means scope of the `submitText` controller not accessible for the `ng-repeat` that's why its not print anything